# Android: How to keep to MVC pattern when it comes to fragment swapping?

Tags: android, android-fragments, model-view-controller

Android is not designed to support the MVC pattern by default. Yet it is possible to organise the code by this pattern to a certain extend.

I keep my activities as small as possible and move all displaying stuff into classes actually inheriting from `View`. Now I am at a point, where I want a view to swap subparts of it.

The technique to swap subparts I found by the documentation is done by the use of fragments and `FragmentTransaction`. This draws controller parts into my view class.

Did anybody get to the same point and found a satisfying solution to keep the controller out of the view?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I came to is in short, don't use fragments, if you want to organise your code by clean MVC pattern. They just mix controller into the view. There are alternative approaches to swap parts of the view.

If you really, really need them, you should likely classify them as part of the view, like you may use small view-models, and keep their job as limited as possible.

The longer answer is, that you should consider, if you really want to apply the MVC pattern. Android is not designed this way. Fragments may be quite useful. If you can't make use of the full features of Android it may be better to trade the MVC pattern.

Android basically has a two layer architecture of model and view, where the view also holds all the controller functionality mixed into it.

Comment: You're right, sigh.  Too bad my work place insists on making Android into an MVC structure, which causes soooo many problems!